# Rails+MongoDB: Find ObjectId bigger than given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, objectid

I am trying to find next (newest) document in MongoDB:

```
Article.find({'_id' => { "$gt" => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(id_from_database)}})
```

But every time I run this query, I get

```
Problem:
  Document(s) not found for class Article with id(s) {"_id"=>{"$gt"=>"given value"}}.
```

I have installed these gems:

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

But still cannot find the issue... I will be grateful for each help!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following will return the next object

```
Article.where({:_id => {:$gt => id_from_database}}).sort({:_id=>1}).first
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call `where` instead of `find` which is used for getting a record by a specific id.

```
Article.where({'_id' => { "$gt" => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(id_from_database)}}).sort(_id: 1).first
```

Comment: But in this case I get this error message: `undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0x007ff71d671b20>`

Comment: You need to add `.first` to the end of that and sort by the `_id`. I'll update the answer.